# How do you install your app on your iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have a developer account, I provisioned a profile etc.

If I plug my iphone into my mac, when I build, will it automatically install the app on my phone also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you **Build and Go** or **Build and Debug** in Device mode in Xcode, then your app will automatically be installed on your device. If the provisioning profile is not on the device, Xcode will also install it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to install apps as a developer.

Build and (Go|Debug) from Xcode,  assuming your build succeeds, and your build settings and provisions and certificates are all correct, and you've enabled "use for development" for your device, cable is hooked up correctly, etc.

Ad Hoc deployment through iTunes syncing (requires an Ad Hoc provision and Distribution certificate to build).